# Process migration

Tags: java, android, process, parallel-processing

I want to migrate a process from android device to a computer, execute the process over my computer and return back to android device. Is it possible to migrate a process between android device and computer?

More details: I will be developing an application that will do some sort of task (say sort a list of 5000 numbers in ascending order). This task will be performed in a function A on an android device. Now, what I want to do is to execute that function on a server (on runtime). The server will not be having the function code in advance. Therefore, when the function is called on android device, the function (process) will migrate to the server (code+input data), execute on the server, and then return sorted list to the android device. Hope you get my question.

Comment: Couldn't you just send a request to a server on your computer to do something, then return it to the client on your device?

Comment: Yes, actually i am doing some research and want to implement all possible solutions. So I really want to implement this :)

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Process migration is a hammer for a non-existent type of nail.

Comment: More details: I will be developing an application that will do some sort of task (say sort a list of 5000 numbers in ascending order). This task will be performed in a function A on an android device. Now, what I want to do is to execute that function on a server (on runtime). The server will not be having the function code in advance. Therefore, when the function is called on android device, the function (process) will migrate to the server (code+input data), execute on the server, and then return sorted list to the android device. Hope you get my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "send process". Generally you will start executing process on the phone then send request to the server and then use ether push or pull to get the result of execution on the server after which you can resume your logic on the phone. Something like REST protocol and using HttpClient in your Android app will be possible solution

Comment: HTTP requests are very slow. More details: I will be developing an application that will do some sort of task (say sort a list of 5000 numbers in ascending order). This task will be performed in a function A on an android device. Now, what I want to do is to execute that function on a server (on runtime). The server will not be having the function code in advance. Therefore, when the function is called on android device, the function (process) will migrate to the server (code+input data), execute on the server, and then return sorted list to the android device. Hope you get my question.

Answer (score 0):

Android has no in-built support for suspending a process in a way that it can be restored as a process somewhere else.

Can you modify the process you want to migrate?  Or are you trying to target arbitrary Android processes?

Android does support primitive, app-aware "suspend" and "resume" (a well behaved Android application is supposed to persist its state so that it can transparently "resume" even its been killed -- see [Android Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle)).  If you control the application in question, you can write the `saveStateInstance` in a platform neutral way and use that on the desktop to "resume" the process, and vice-versa.  Depending on your definition of "process migration" this may or may not count.

There is nothing in theory from preventing a more robust process migration from being added to Android (it should be a bit easier to migrate a Java-based process), but you will run into [all the standard process migration issues](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Dejan_Milojicic/pm7.pdf) (network identity, local resource usage, and open network connections being the standard stumbling blocks).

Comment: More details: I will be developing an application that will do some sort of task (say sort a list of 5000 numbers in ascending order). This task will be performed in a function A on an android device. Now, what I want to do is to execute that function on a server (on runtime). The server will not be having the function code in advance. Therefore, when the function is called on android device, the function (process) will migrate to the server (code+input data), execute on the server, and then return sorted list to the android device. Hope you get my question.